# 400 Bad Request response to calling web api localhost/token url for generating token

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2, angular7, bearer-token

I have enabled cors for my web api and it works fine for all the allowanonymous methods for now

```
        // Enable CORS for the Angular App
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

But when I try to access the below url from my angular app to get token, I get the response 400 Bad Request.

```
    const userData = 'username=' + email + '&password=' + ppassword + '&grant_type=password';
    const reqHeader = new HttpHeaders(
        {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'No-Auth': 'True',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:59255/token', userData, {headers: reqHeader});
```

How can I resolve this if at all this is an issue?

Comment: What’s the exact error message the browser logs in the devtools console? What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: @sideshowbarker - Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:59255/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: The server is responding to your request with 400 Bad Request. That’s the problem you need to fix. You don’t have a CORS problem. That 400 error isn’t caused by your CORS configuration. It”s caused by your frontend code not sending the right kind of request. The reason you see that CORS message is, 4xx errors usually don’t include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Check the server logs on the server side of the server you’re sending that request to, and find what information the server is logging about exactly what is broken in your request that leads the server to send the 400 response.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - Looks like the problems was with CORS. I just added app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); in my startup file and the issue was resolved. Anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this because more people need to see how CORS can be so tricky at times. I removed the EnableCors code completely from my WebApiConfig file. Then I added the below line in my Startup file

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

This resolved my issue. There is definetly an issue with the order of how cors is integrated in the application. Feel free to add more